# Android widget update the existing views

Tags: android

I am developing an Android widget. I have an initial layout from the XML for my widget.

But I issued a webservice call and need to update the view according to the response from the webservice.

```
public void changeTheApartmentTo(Context context, int position){
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.header_text, objj.get(position).getDistance());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_name_row, objj.get(position).getName());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_address_row, objj.get(position).getStreet());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_state_row, objj.get(position).getState());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_price_row, objj.get(position).getPrice());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_bedbath_row, objj.get(position).getBathrooms());
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img_apartment, ImageLoader.getInstance().get(objj.elementAt(position).getImageUrl()));

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

Above is a function I have written in the `public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider`
class.

When I am changing the views, it results in a null pointer error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you call this method? Tell us how you get this exception?

You can use something like:

```
public static void updateWidgets(Context ctx) {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.yourAppWidgetLayout);

    //Do your updating...

    ComponentName appWidget = new ComponentName(ctx, YourAppWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctx);
    awm.updateAppWidget(appWidget, views);
}
```